# PyQGIS add WMS layer with CQL_FILTER

Tags: qgis, python, wms, pyqgis, cql-filter

I'd like to add a WMS layer through my QGIS plugin with custom CQL_FILTER parameters. My problem is, that the CQL_FILTER parameters are not passed to the GeoServer (I can see it in the GeoServer log at the GetMap query: "CQLFilter = null").

This is what I've tried:

```
registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance()    
urlWithParams = "cql_filter=BBOX(geom, 579465,125671,664692,167717)&crs=EPSG:23700&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=master&styles=&url=http://localhost:9090/geoserver/myWorkspace/wms"
rlayer = QgsRasterLayer (urlWithParams , "my_title", "wms")
registry.addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

The WMS layer is added to the map with no problem, but all the features are visible on the layer even outside the BBOX I defined in the parameters.
When I use the GeoServer's built-in CQL_FILTER builder (with the layer preview) the same filter works as desired.

Does anyone have a solution or a workaround for this?

I use QGIS 2.4.0-Chugiak.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using PyQgis 2.x

```
 registry = QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance() urlWithParams =
 "crs=EPSG:21037&IgnoreGetMapUrl=1&featureCount=10&format=image/png&styles=&layers=parcels&url=http://localhost:8060/geoserver/cadastralWsp/wms%3FCQL_FILTER=BBOX(geom,
 579465,125671,664692,167717)" rlayer = QgsRasterLayer (urlWithParams
 , "my_parcels", "wms") registry.addMapLayer(rlayer)
```

if you are using PyQgis 3.x

```
urlWithParams = "contextualWMSLegend=0&IgnoreGetMapUrl=1&crs=EPSG:32643&dpiMode=7&featureCount=10&format=image/png&layers=bldg&styles&url=http://localhost:8080/geoserver/Testing/wms%3FCQL_FILTER=BBOX(geom, 579465,125671,664692,167717)"
vLayer = QgsRasterLayer(urlWithParams, 'Output', 'wms')
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(vLayer)
```